# How do I Integrate Entity Framework with External REST Data Source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, entity-framework-4

I am creating my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and my data comes from a data source I can access only via its REST API.

I will only be using READ-ONLY access at this point to the REST data source (no updating, etc.)

I would like to use the Entity Framework V4 to provide a Business Entity interface to MVC 3 without exposing it to the REST API.

I need to get something working quickly - so I don't have time to fully understand the Server Layer / UnitOfWork and Repository patterns just yet, although I plan to go there next.

I am willing to use a Repository class at this time, but not ready for DI / IoC container yet.

Any suggestions on where the RESP API calls go?

EDIT

Learned by asking this question that it is not necessarily useful to integrate an ORM with a REST API - See my accepted answer below.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You want to put an ORM on top of a REST API?

Comment: I guess you are correct, that's probably unreasonable no?  If I am making MVC 3 app, should I put REST calls in my Model classes and return strongly typed IEnumerable<T> for something like a GetAll()?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Object/Relational Mapper, or ORM, like Entity Framework has specifically been developed to abstract away a relational database. It might not be the right fit for REST calls.

You could instead build a repository class that encapsulates the REST call and exposes methods like `IEnumerable<T> GetAll()` or `T GetyById(...)`.